# Execute global javascript code anonymously

Tags: javascript, browser

I have the following html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="before.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="globalCode.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="after.js"></script>
```

The `globalCode.js` file contains:

```
function doStuff() {
    return 1 + 2;
}

module.export = doStuff();
```

I want to get the contents of `module.export` but without letting `doStuff()` get into the global context.

So basically I would like the following functionality:

```
var module = {};
(function() {
    function doStuff() {
        return 1 + 2;
    }

    module.export = doStuff();
}();
```

with the restriction that I can not modify `globalCode.js` and can only use `before.js` & `after.js`.

I thought about saving the global object in `before.js` and restoring it in `after.js` but I am not quite sure how.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to work with some CommonJS style code. Have you considered using [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)? It compiles code written using CommonJS (`module.exports` style modules) and makes it work correctly in the browser.

Comment: As I said I can not modify the code.

Comment: You wouldn't be modifying the source code with a bundler.

Comment: Hm I want to test the code. But it is not CommonJs. It is a format historically build in my company so I guess browserify will not be compatible.

Comment: Post the format if you are allowed. In a worst case scenario, you can turn your companies proprietary module format into whatever you want with an AST parser. Again, that would leave the source code untouched.

Comment: @eclipse [It sure looks a lot like CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1).

Comment: So just to clariy: What I want to do is not possible by somehow processing the global object?! Because I want to be able to debug the code.